# SCCM client not booting up

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm

I have installed and configured SCCM, but, I'm getting the following error;

Booting from filename "SMSBoot\x64\wdsnbp.com" tftp://192.168.100.x/SMSBoot%5cx64%5cwdsnbp.com. File not found (0x2d12603b) Could not boot from filename "SMSBoot\x64\wdsnbp.com": File notfound (0x2d12603b) No more network devices

I've tried the steps given above, where unchecking of PXE and checking it back on is mentioned. But, it didn't work for me.

Any suggestion / link would be appreciated which could get me out it this situation. :)

Comment: Is your windows firewall allowing access? Can you download the boot file from a machine with a TFTP client installed?

Comment: Thanks Tim for a quick reply. Yes, the firewall is disabled. I am still unable to make it work. The DHCP server is providing IP to the machine on boot. But, when it tries to access ftp://192.168.100.x/SMSBoot%5cx64%5cwdsnbp.com, it says that the File not found.

Comment: I tried using the linux tftp client and accessed the location mentioned above, and it reflect with, "Error code 4: Transfer mode not supported"

Answer (score 0):

do you realize that the address is not valid?  `tftp://192.168.100.x/SMSBoot%5cx64%5cwdsnbp.com`

`192.168.100.x` this is not a TFTP server address...

You should try a Wireshark traffic capture and see what PXE info the DHCP server is really providing and what is the PXE client really requesting.